# Microsoft graph API webhook change notifications - how much time after a change

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

After registering to webhook subscription for mail or user resources - What is the expected time between a change occur till our subscribed endpoint will receive the change notification?

Answer (score 0):

The time to deliver notifications varies depending on the service load and other factors. Under normal conditions you should receive notifications within 5 minutes of the actual change.

Comment: Is there an issue with webhook notifications?! I have been testing webhook notifications with a new development Azure tenant and I am able to successfully create the notifications subscription for /users (update,deleted) and confirmed they are active (list subscriptions API) and yet I am NOT getting any notifications at all.  It is entirely 100% frustrating that this does NOT work.  I truly don't understand how Azure, as mature as it is, and as highly available as it should be is STILL having important features like this still NOT USABLE. And there seems to no concern or urgency either. SMH.

Comment: sorry about the bad experience. If you are not receiving receiving notifications, or if they take time to be delivered and you've ruled out for sure the issue does not come from the receiving side (notification URL and code/infrastructure supporting it), you should start a support request from the azure and/or office 365 administration portal.